# how to see new inserted data in textbox ? (java netbeans mysql)

Tags: mysql, netbeans, insert

I have a MySQL database in NetBeans.
When I add new data in my database by insert button, I can see my new data in output windows (because I have a code to print all data in database), but I don't know why I can't see my new data in textboxes, it means when I navigate fields by next, previous buttons I can't see my new data !!!!!!
But, when I close the program and run it again, my textboxes show my new data !

What's reason???????

my Next button code :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id"));
            String s = rs.getString("name");
            String n = rs.getString("profession");

            txtID.setText(Integer.toString(x));
            txtName.setText(s);
            txtProfession.setText(n);
        } else {
            rs.previous();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

My insert button code :

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO sample (id,name,profession) VALUES ('"+txtID.getText()+"','"+txtName.getText()+"','"+txtProfession.getText()+"');");
        st.executeQuery("Select * from sample");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming **ResultSet rs** is a class level variable, with in your method jButton3ActionPerformed() change the following

```
st.executeQuery("Select * from sample");
```

to

```
rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from sample");
```

one suggestion is, you should close your database resources once you fetch the data and you can construct your Collection to hold the data for further processing.

The pagination that you are trying to use is not good practice

Comment: oh my dear friend thanx a lot.
you help me a lot.
you make me happy thanx a world.